# Plotting continuous line in Gnuplot for frequency count

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot

I am trying to plot the frequency count of the following values available in (test_plot_bins.txt) in Gnuplot

```
-0.355534673
0.13217762
-0.842048585
-0.131302223
0.03265043
0.190827265
-0.25680709
-0.072149448
-0.156086803
0.065009468
-0.003330263
-0.059023393
-0.017556788
-0.06090761
-0.205948548
-0.18360047
```

using this script

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot -persist

    
clear
reset
set key off
set border 3

set boxwidth 0.05 absolute

set style fill solid 1.0 noborder      
    
  
bin_width = 0.01;
bin_number(x) = floor(x/bin_width)
rounded(x) = bin_width * ( bin_number(x) + 0.5 )
  

plot 'test_plot_bins.txt' using (rounded($1)) :(1) smooth frequency with boxes
```

Here is the result. How do I change it that it becomes a normal line plot?

[image: Plot1]

Secondly, when I replicate a value so that its count becomes 2 and then plot it, it stands out and diminishes other values. Here is how it looks like

[image: Plot2]

How do I scale the plot that other values with count of 1 are also visible?

Comment: Your title and problem description don't match.  You're drawing a histogram essentially, which there is a build-in style already.

Comment: @karakfa I don't know how to draw line and I used histogram so I can at least visualize how the data looks like

Comment: `set style data lines`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a line plot you can replace `with boxes` by `with lines`. However this is probably not the best way to display this sort of binned data. I suggest using the on-line demo [bins.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.2/bins.html)as a guide.  I copy it here for reference.

```
#
# Demo illustrating the relationship between
# a binned histogram and a kernel density model of the same data.
#
$DATA << EOD
1   1
2   1
8   1
9   1
17  1
17  1
9   1
9   1
5   1
7   1
7   1
8   1
8   1
8   1
10  1
11  1
11  1
12  1
14  1
3   1
3   1
3   1
8   7
15  1
17  1
17  1
18  1
19  1
20  1
EOD

set title "Comparison of a binned histogram and\na kernel density model of the same data"

set style data lines
set xtics 1 norangelimit nomirror
set grid y
set yrange [0:5.5]
set style fill solid 0.5 noborder
set jitter spread 0.5

plot $DATA using 1 bins=20 with boxes title '20 bins', \
        '' using 1:(1) smooth kdensity bandwidth .5 lw 2 title 'smooth kdensity', \
        '' using 1:(.9) with impulse lc "black" title 'jittered data'
```

[image]

Notes:

- `bins=20` will automatically divide the data into 20 equal-width bins along x. There is an optional keyword `binrange` but if no binrange is given, the range is taken from the extremes of the x values found in the data.
- The `set jitter` command adds a small displacement to points, or in this case impulses, that would otherwise lie exactly on top of each other.  It has no effect on the boxes or lines.
- `smooth kdensity` is one of many options for producing a smooth line. For full documentation see the gnuplot documentation.  It generates a function f(x) in which each point in the data set acts as the center of a Gaussian weighted by distance from x; the resulting curve is the sum of these contributions.  Selecting a bandwidth smaller than the spacing between points insures that each local maximum gets its own peak.
- Each of the three representations, `boxes`, `lines`, and `impulses` could be plotted independently.  This plot combines all three modes for comparison.

Comment: could you comment the code. It could be hard to understand for someone from Matlab background